# How to keep adding text box on every click using ngIf

Tags: html, angular

On the event of a button click, I am adding a new field box on the screen.
But this happens only for one click. I want to know how can I achieve to keep adding field boxes every time the button clicks?

Here is my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgsfrm

Comment: I think you forgot to fork in StackBlitz. Link navigates to an empty StackBlitz angular project.

Comment: yeah , i updated it now

Comment: There's a doubt in the requirement. What field you want to add? As of now, new field is added by using a `Boolean` to make it visible. Could you please explain the exact logic to be applied there?

Comment: I want a new field 'via' to be added on every click of the add via button. As of now, the button does not add anew field from second click onwards.

Comment: This is what you want. Have a look . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add new fields by using [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor) instead of `ngIf`. The amount of fields can be based on the contents of an `Array` for instance. [You can check out how to do this in my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iyjcqg):

```js
<input *ngFor="let fieldValue of fields" placeholder="{{fieldValue}}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I have simplified a bit your example: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-muulft)

Basically you are gonna need an array of strings to store all `via` values:

```
viaFields: Array<string> = ['']
```

Then simply display these using an `*ngFor` loop and `[(ngModel)]` for data binding:

```html
<button (click)="addField()"> + Add Via</button>
<input
  *ngFor="let field of viaFields; let in = index; trackBy: trackByFn"
  [(ngModel)]="viaFields[in]">
```